# "DataBase encryption in Hibernate" returns Unknown column 'encryptedBody' in 'field list'

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, encryption, fieldlist

I was using the method that was referenced in andrescanavesi's answer to [DataBase encryption in Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621422/database-encryption-in-hibernate) and I get the following error:

> Unknown column 'encryptedBody' in 'field list'

the generated sql is:

```
select AES_DECRYPT(
          partssns5_.encryptedBody,
          '8269b021365180477478ba97d881db71d05a1')
    AS PSS_SSN_4_264_4_  from part_ssn partssns5_;
```

encryptedbody is defined in mysql as varbinary

any ideas???

Answer (score 0):

Ooops,

Don't know how many times I have done that as a developer, but I was testing SQL Workbench in the correct db,  but the application was pointing to a different db, where that column did not exist.

Ooops.

Sorry about that.